# Is it possible to reorganize the default CEs in another Groups?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I would like to group several default typo3 CE into one group.
Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean in the New Content Element wizard tabs or in the `Type` select box optgroups in a content element?

Comment: Yes the "New Content Element" Wizard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The New Content Element Wizard can be changed with Page TSconfig. For example if you want the content element type `html` in the first tab, you can do the following:

```
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.common {
  elements {
    html < mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.special.elements.html
  }
  show := addToList(html)
}
```

You can add a tab and fill it with an existing element like this:

```
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.myTab {
  header = My tab
  elements {
    html < mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.special.elements.html
  }
  show = html
}
```

To remove the existing type from its original tab, add:

```
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.special.show := removeFromList(html)
```

More on this you can find here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/PageTsconfig/Mod.html#newcontentelement-wizarditems